# Авторизация в VK на PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Очень простой (надеюсь) вопрос. В php-файл, например, post-запросом приходит логин и пароль. Реализовать нужно следующее: авторизация вк успешна - я получаю имя, фамилию, айди пользователя. Всё.
Какое приложение в VK мне лучше создавать? Iframe? Прочитал документацию, не очень разобрался, надеюсь вы поможете) Хотя бы поставьте на верный путь, что почитать можно об этом и тд.

Comment: Если честно - ничего не понял )) вам нужно сделать авторизацию VK ? если вы не делали авторизацию то о чём идёт речь тут   "авторизация вк успешна - я получаю имя....."     что за IFRAME?

Comment: Официально ВК не разрешает кому попало авторизовываться по логину и паролю. Вам нужно использовать [OAuth](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user) или каким-то способом имитировать действия пользователя в браузере.

Comment: @Arsen я как раз о том, что нужно реализовать

Comment: @mymedia ну то есть, если httpurlconnection к php-файлу сделать, это же будет имитацией? или нужно, чтобы пользователь, нажимая кнопку в java-проекте, переходил в браузер сам?